# Azure Database Web Edition - Can't finish query because timeout (1 minute)

Tags: sql, database, azure, timeout

I have an Azure SQL database. It is the web edition with 1 GB of max space.
Now I want to (as an example) change the type of one column with this SQL query command:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname nvarchar(100) NOT NULL;
```

The table has about 1 million records so it takes some time. The problem is that my query can't finish because of the 1 minute timeout. I need a little bit more than just one minute. 1 minute is a joke. How can I fix this? I need more time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform such a big query on a Shared Instance. Change the Plan so that the Database runs on a Dedicated Server Instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which plans are with dedicated server instances? I tried the basic plan of the new database service tiers but it got a lot worse and timeout was the same.